# DotVVM Master Page and inheritance

Tags: dotvvm

I am considering using DotVVM for an existing webforms application.
(It is a Government Intranet app)
It uses Web Experience Toolkit and CDTS- Centrally Deployed Templates Solution which can at any time automatically replace files such as master pages and css with updated versions.
For that reason, I want to ensure that this will be compatible with DotVVM especially with regards to the master pages and class hierarchy which I cannot change.
A page in the app has the following class hierarchy:
Page <-  SolutionBasePage  <-  BasePage <-  BasePage from CDTS DLL <- System.Web.UI.Page
I can only change the first 3
Tips and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but DotVVM is using different classes than the Web Forms - there are no dependencies on `System.Web`.

The ViewModel of a DotVVM page can be any class, but it must be JSON-serializable (which `System.Web.UI.Page` is not). Additionally, it should implement `IDotvvmViewModel`; otherwise many features of the framework may not be accessible.

What may be possible to do is some kind of adapter between DotVVM ViewModel and the page base classes from the Web Forms. The ViewModel would contain the base page as a field (not as a property as it shouldn't be serialized and sent to the client) and would only use the page properties and methods.

But I am not sure how difficult would this be to integrate.